# Variable number of elements in SceneBuilder for JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am using Scene Builder to Design an GUI for JavaFX. I am cloning some 2048 like game that can have more row and columns (user-input). I want to know is there any way to implement these variable number of blocks in Scene Builder in JavaFX or not.

My program works completely fine on stdin-stdout (The code is to big to include all of it here but If you want an specific part, I can add the code here) and I want to port it to JavaFX. The main problem is that I don't know whether I need to code this variable size number of blocks in JavaFX or not? Can this task be done using Scene Builder without needing to code this?

Maybe my question is too basic but I am completely new to Java Graphics. So if the question is duplicate, please mention the actual topic and I will delete this post.

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: FXML files, which Scene Builder generates, are typically used for the static elements of a UI. If part of your UI is dynamic (or would benefit from being generated in a loop) then you should implement that part of the behavior in code.

Comment: You do not implement anything with SceneBuilder. You just create some data file `FXMLLoader` is able to use to use to create a scene. (Newer versions of SceneBuilder may allow you to add javascript though, which would allow you to actually write some code, but this would imho be less desireable than using java code.)